# How to send notifications to same user on multiple browsers/devices in firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to implement FCM to our application, however it seems like a new token is generated on each new device or browser, so when a new token is generated it sets their registration id in the database which we then use to send notifications to.

This means that if I go to our web app, then our web app on my mobile and get a notification, my mobile is the only one getting it.

How can this be handled so I can send notification to both my mobile safari and my web browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should collect and store all the registration tokens for all the devices that a user may be using.  You can go further and define a device group for that user, [as described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group).